# Can't find ""Save Results" Button in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

After I run my query in Google Bigquery UI, I can see my results, but cannot find the "Save Result" button to export the results as Google Sheets. Do I need to change any settings, or is my result table too large? Below is a snapshot of what I see.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w77g.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some bug. Try cleaning the cache in your browser. Also try "HIDE PREVIEW FEATURES" button.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! "Hide Preview Features" worked.